# scala for...yield excludes empty strings

Tags: scala, for-comprehension

In the code below

```
test("duplicatedParamGetsFirst2") {
  val str = "A=B&C" //"A=B&A=C"
  val res = for {
    x <- str.split("&")
    y <- if(x.indexOf("=") == -1) "" else x.substring(x.indexOf("=") + 1)
  } yield (if (x.indexOf("=") == -1) x else x.substring(0, x.indexOf("=")), y)
  res.foreach(x => println(x))
}
```

I expected the result (A,B)(C,) but I got just (A,B). How do I fix it?

Comment: Added [a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45788132/913286) to generate an array of pairs

Answer (score 1):

Your goal isn't completely clear. Maybe this gets close.

```
"A=B&C".split("&").map(_.split("="))
// res0: Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array(A, B), Array(C))
```

You can use `.toList`, or some other collection cast, if you don't want the result in `Array`s.

Answer (score 1):

[Leo C's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45787968/913286) works. Here is another snippet, generating an array of pairs, close in style to your original code:

```
val s = "A=B&C"
val res = for {
  t <- s.split("&")
  a = t.split("=")
} yield a(0) -> a.lift(1).getOrElse("") 

res.foreach(println)
// (A,B)
// (C,)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure the result date type is what you want, as your for-comprehension will yield an `Array` of `Tuple2[String, Char]` because `y` would be of type `Char` when generated from `String` `x`.  A simple way to generate your tuples would be to apply `split` twice as follows:

```
val str = "A=B&C"

str.split("&").
  map( x => if (x contains "=") x.split("=") else Array(x, "") ).
  map{ case Array(a, b) => (a, b) }

// res1: Array[(String, String)] = Array((A,B), (C,""))
```

If you must use for-comprehension, here's one way to do it:

```
val res = for {
  x <- str.split("&")
} yield if (x contains "=")
    x.split("=") match { case Array(a, b) => (a, b) } else
      (x, "")

// res2: Array[(String, String)] = Array((A,B), (C,""))
```

Answer (score 0):

The code should be:

```
val str = "A=B&C" //"A=B&A=C"
val res = for {
  x <- str.split("&")
} yield
{
  val y = if(x.indexOf("=") == -1) "" else x.substring(x.indexOf("=") + 1)
  (if (x.indexOf("=") == -1) x else x.substring(0, x.indexOf("=")), y)
}
res.foreach(x => println(x))
```

About the for( expressA  express B), I don't know how to express it.